# Cannot use polyglossia/babel with biblatex in LuaTeX: etoolbox Toggle undefined

Tags: biblatex, luatex, babel, polyglossia

This is an example `test.tex` document. Both babel and polyglossia failed and produce the same error:

```latex
\documentclass{book}

%\usepackage[vietnamese]{babel}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{vietnamese}

\usepackage{biblatex}


\title{Sth}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[This](https://pastebin.com/PaKuF6zc) is the full log. And my config for VS Code:

```json
"latex-workshop.latex.recipes": [
    {
        "name": "lualatex->biber",
        "tools": [
            "lualatex",
            // "biber",
        ]
    }
],
"latex-workshop.latex.tools": [
    {
        "name": "lualatex",
        "command": "lualatex",
        "args": [
            "--shell-escape",
            "-synctex=1",
            "-interaction=nonstopmode",
            "-file-line-error",
            "-pdf",
            "%DOC%"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "biber",
        "command": "biber",
        "args": [
            "%DOCFILE%"
        ]
    }
],
```

I installed all Vietnamese-related package I found using `tlmgr search`, notably babel-vietnamese and vntex, to no avail.

When I use English language, it works. When I paste the exact document to Overleaf, it also works. So it's something on my part. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That was a bug in `biblatex` v3.15 and v3.15a related to https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/945.

It was be fixed in `biblatex` v3.16 from 2020-12-31.

**If you still have this problem, update your system.**

---

### Old answer in case you are stuck with an old version of `biblatex` that cannot be updated

For now you can manually define the undefined toggles that might be used (in your case the for the fallback `emglish` and for `vietnamese`).

```
\documentclass{book}

%\usepackage[vietnamese]{babel}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{vietnamese}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\providetoggle{blx@lang@captions@english}
\providetoggle{blx@lang@captions@vietnamese}

\title{Sth}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```