# Recompiling on another newer iMac I obtain error: "./LibroOrange.tex:187: Package etoolbox Error: Toggle 'blx@lang@captions@latin' undefined."

Tags: biblatex, etoolbox, undefined

Recompiling on another newer iMac my big book, I obtain error:

```
./LibroOrange.tex:187: Package etoolbox Error: Toggle 'blx@lang@captions@latin'  undefined.
```

But pressing RETURN seems to solve: the compiler continues and the pdf is generated apparently in the right way.

Ideas?

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/562073/2388

Comment: Thanks. But it seems that polyglossia is not compatible with pdflatex...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Ulrike Fischer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2388/ulrike-fischer) already linked to [Cannot use polyglossia/babel with biblatex in LuaTeX: etoolbox Toggle undefined](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/562068/35864) [in the comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/563079/recompiling-on-another-newer-imac-i-obtain-error-libroorange-tex187-packag#comment1419310_563079) and that is indeed the same issue. The bug was fixed version 3.16 of `biblatex`.

**Update you TeX system to get rid of this error.**

---

## Old answer with workaround in case you are stuck with an old version of `biblatex`.

Since there was some confusion about whether or not the answer applies only for `polyglossia`, here is an example using `babel`.

The core of the answer is to have the line

```
\providetoggle{blx@lang@captions@<language>}
```

if the main document language `<language>` has no `biblatex` localisation file (`.lbx` file). (That explains why there is an error with `latin`, for which there is no `.lbx` file, but not with `ngerman`, `french`, or `english`, all of which have an `.lbx` file.)

The following example compiles without error again

```
\documentclass[latin]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\providetoggle{blx@lang@captions@latin}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Arma virumque cano \autocite{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Adding "\providetoggle{blx@lang@captions@latin}" as you suggested, solved the problem! Strangely the problem is limited to "latin" but I use also ngerman, italian, and english in my document... great! many thanks!

Comment: @SimoneCorelli I added a few words about that.