# Biblatex with LatexBangla

Tags: biblatex, xetex, babel, polyglossia

I have a document (Texstudio in OSX) written using the LatexBangla package (XeLaTex system). But I am unable incorporate a bibliography in English written using biblatex (biber). The minimal code is given below.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,onesided, notitlepage]{article}
%\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[banglamainfont=Kalpurush,
banglattfont=Siyam Rupali
]{latexbangla}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=alphabetic,sorting=nyt, language=english,autolang=other]{biblatex}
\begin{document}
Hello
 \end{document}
```

I get the following error -

```
line 7: Package etoolbox Error: Toggle 'blx@lang@captions@bengali' undefined. \begin{document}
: 'babel/polyglossia' detected but 'csquotes' missing.
: Unused global option(s): [onesided].
: Language 'bengali' not supported.
: No file bengali_test.bbl.
: There were undefined references.
: Please (re)run Biber on the file:(biblatex) bengali_test(biblatex) and rerun LaTeX afterwards.
```

Comment: Maybe this answer helps? [https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/562073](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/562073/110998)

Comment: It doesn't work. I get same error even after updating!

Comment: I just managed to compile the MWE (with slightly different font settings) without the `etoolbox` error. (I'm using `biblatex` v3.16) What version of `biblatex` are you running? Please upload the *complete* `.log` file of a the failing run to a text-sharing website such as https://pastebin.com/ or https://gist.github.com/.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/qPcgwWDE

Comment: Delete the `.aux`, `.bbl` and `.bcf` file. Then run XeLaTeX again. (The error about `'blx@lang@captions@bengali' undefined` is no longer present. You get a very different error in the `.aux` file now.)

Comment: It worked on this code! But, I have to check if it works on my original code.

Comment: Any news here? Did you manage to compile your original document?

Comment: Thanks for asking. I did manage to compile it fine. But the bibliography is empty for some reason. I am trying to fix that.

Comment: The following errors arise in the minimal file above (I just added a reference): https://pastebin.com/W4w8f3Ev

Comment: The error you initially asked about is definitely resolved. The `.log` you show does not report any errors, but it says that your citation `bhatt-perfectoid` is undefined. Are you sure the citation is contained in your `.bib` file? Is the entry key correct? Did you run XeLaTeX, Biber, XeLaTeX, XeLaTeX? Did Biber report any issues in the `.blg` file? Can you run https://gist.github.com/moewew/6f24521919be979a478ceb0ffde20153 (without any modifications, the `.bib` file used there will be found automatically on your system)?

Comment: I tried. It doesn't work work with XeLaTex (empty bibliography). It works with pdflatexmk.

However my original document doesn't work with XeTex, or LuaLaTex (message:  XeTeX is required to compile this document.* Sorry!) or pdflatexmk. With XeLaTex it produces empty bibliography. The bibliography is fine as the SAME document produces a bibliography when I change language from LatexBangla to babel English.

Comment: *Just* running XeLaTeX is not enough to get a bibliography. You will have to run XeLaTeX, Biber, XeLaTeX, XeLaTeX. `pdflatexmk` does all of that for you automatically behind the scenes (with pdfLaTeX instead of XeLaTeX) that's why you don't have to run Biber explicitly. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864 to find out how to configure your editor to help you run Biber for you. I don't quite understand the last error and it does not appear to have anything to do with `biblatex`. Note that there usually is a difference between running XeTeX and XeLaTeX: you want the latter.

Comment: I put biber in it and managed to run it with a simple bibliography. https://pastebin.com/ELkpUcWi was the log file.
However, it a different bibliography and when I changed to my original bibliography it was not working. So I deleted all filed (.log, .aux, etc.) and rerun it, it didn't work. Since then I cannot get it to work EVEN on the SIMPLE bibliography.  New log file https://pastebin.com/tGkJFXRP

Comment: The `.log` of the file where the bibliography does not work reports `file 'paper.bbl' not found.` which suggest that you did not run Biber after running XeLaTeX (or that you did, but Biber stopped early due to an error). Run XeLaTeX, Biber, XeLaTeX, XeLaTeX in that order.

Comment: I have the following setting. https://imgur.com/a/IJEnEEZ

Comment: I voted to close the question as a duplicate of the one linked above, since the main issue mentioned in the title and the body text is covered by the duplicate. There seemed to be some other unrelated issues that prevented generation of the bibliography here. If you still have a problem with those, I'd urge you to ask a new question with a new MWE and an accurate description of your settings (editor settings) and what is going on.